# Color of the drawn gradient is always uniform

Tags: python, tkinter

I tried to write my own simple function to draw gradient (only grey colours) by using very naive method (drawing sequence of lines), but actaully the colour of the rectangle which represents the gradient is always an uniform colour (I think it is the latest colour from the loop). Could you explain me why, please? Here is the code:

```
import Tkinter

class testGUI:
    def __init__( self, root ):
        C = Tkinter.Canvas( root, bg = "blue", height = 250, width = 300 )
        self.drawGradient( C, 10, 10, 100, 50 )
        C.pack()

    def drawGradient( self, canvas, x, y, w, h ):
        for offset in range( 0, w ):
            gradColor = '#%02x%02x%02x' % ( x * 10, x * 10, x * 10 )
            canvas.create_line( x + offset, y, x + offset, y + h, fill = gradColor )

root = Tkinter.Tk()
app = testGUI( root )
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The color is always the same because the color you are using does not depend on the iteration of the loop:

```
for offset in ...
    gradColor = '#%02x%02x%02x' % ( x * 10, x * 10, x * 10 )
```

To make it change, the value of `gradColor` must depend on the value of `offset`, for instance:

```
def drawGradient(self, canvas, x, y, w, h):
    factor = 255./w
    for offset in range(0, w):
        gradColor = '#%02x%02x%02x' % (offset*factor, offset*factor, offset*factor)
        canvas.create_line(x + offset, y, x + offset, y + h, fill=gradColor)
```

Comment: omg... I just had my loop as "for x in..." but wanted the name to be "offset" and forgot about the x. Thanks